# How can you squeeze a cardboard cup as if it was stepped on or sat on?

Tags: modeling

Made a model of a classic cardboard cup (like from Starbucks, for example). But it should lie on a floor as if it was already from trash can.  Have no idea, how to do that :(

Here is a photo reference:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you want to deform it like in your picture? Have you tried Sculpt mode?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 2):

### Case A: Sculpting

Yeah, it was my first thought, but generally I prefer to stick to non destructive modeling methods. However in this exact case it was the best option.

1. Make a cylinder
2. In *Edit Mode*: select bottom face, scale it down as needed
3. in the *Subidivision* modifier press *Apply*
4. Sculpt as desired in sculpt mode (I choose multi-plane scrape to make it look more like cardboard material)

*Optionally*, to make a border on the top of the cup:

1. Under the *Solidify* modifier press *Apply*
2. Select the top edge loop and the edge
   loop right under it, select loop inner-region, extrude faces
   along normals as desired
3. Select these two loops again, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to
   bevel it

Here is the final model:
[image]

### Case B: Displace modifier.

Yeah, it was my first thought, but generally I prefer to stick to non destructive modeling methods. However in this exact case it was the best option.

1. Make a cylinder
2. In *Edit Mode*: select bottom face, scale it down as needed
3. In *Edit Mode*: add some loop cuts on the cylinder, select created vertexes, create vertex group and assign vertexes to it
4. *Subidivision* modifier
5. Two displace modifiers (I have these settings). Let it affect only the vertex group

[image] [image]

*Optionally*, to squeeze it more:

1. Select object, press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, choose selection to cursor
2. Add *Lattice*, scale it to fit the object
3. Select cup, add *Lattice* modifier, object to created lattice
4. Try to move the upper vertexes of the lattice in *Edit Mode*. Gotta work

Here is the final model:
[image]